# Drag and drop over 2 different views

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, drag-and-drop

I have this following problem which I can't seem solve:

In my top view (a menu bar), I have a `UIButton` on which I want the user to press and then drag and drop an object (OpenGL object that spawns fine) to the view under the menu bar (an `EAGLView`).  My problem is that I cannot pass the touch location of where the user presses down on the button to the `EAGLView`.

I have tried several solutions :

1. Assign a selector to the Drag-In-Touch function of the `UIButton`.  This allows me to get the touch position I could want, but this location only stays in bounds of the view holding the `UIButton` (the menu bar)
2. Override the `touchesBegan`/`Moved`/`Ended` of the `UIButton` so they use the touches of the `nextResponder.nextResponder` (making this the `EAGLView`).  This seemed to work for the `touchesBegan`, but the second I try to move around, `touchesMoved` is called once and then stops.

If any of you could point me to any possible ways of accomplishing what I want, I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely answering the question here, but what you want could be solved by adding UIviews instead of UIButtons and dragging them on screen using a Pangesture recognizer.  Then, you simply load or place the object you want under this view at the moment the user ends the pan/drag motion.